# Which wallets are supporting SEP-0007

Tags: wallets

I am curious which wallets are supporting [SEP-0007 - URI Scheme to facilitate delegated signing](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md) already or have it on their roadmap for the near future.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 2):

Mooney is the first wallet to support uri schemes according to SEP-007.

However, it is only for payments, inflation, trustlines and offers, signing transactions will be available in version 2.0.

https://github.com/kuyawa/Mooney

(This is one of my projects)

Answer (score 2):

cosmic-lib (javascript) will support it, so will Stellar Authenticator which depends on it.

This will take a little time, though, as there's a lot of requirement to get right like multi-signature and accurate description of every kind of operation.

Edit:
This will mostly be of use for the installable applications built on JavaScript. Stellar Authenticator will handle those links only on Firefox and Chrome browsers in desktops environment. This is because the standard is based on a browser-specific feature: https://caniuse.com/#feat=registerprotocolhandler . I should have made this clear from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I'll likely *generate* a few transactions using this in StellarGuard, as multisig setup is the most complicated part of onboarding so far and I'm just sending people to Stellar Labs or copy the XDR themselves.

As far as registering handlers, the story around multisig in that SEP is a bit murky, so I'm not quite sure how I should approach it. I'll likely let people scan QR codes with these URIs to import them, but probably won't register a URI handler. Waiting to see how things shake out.

Comment: In your case I believe the more logical is to delegate signing to the wallets which should in turn transmit the transaction to StellarGuard through the API.

This should be noted that the web services will have very poor support of this standard anyway, as the only way to comply is through a browser-specific functionality : https://caniuse.com/#feat=registerprotocolhandler . The only on-browser solution is making an extension as Kuyawa does.