# What tool is used for browser interactivity?

Tags: security, new-developer

The use-case is I would like someone to buy an asset directly on a website, by clicking GUI-buttons and preferring client-side code, rather than asking them to write code or give a server their keys.

I saw these:

- https://pay.meta.re/
- https://github.com/HerveKoener/ULASafe

The first positions itself as explicitly a metamask equivalent, but is limited to XLM transfers.

What design patterns are used to create browser-based dApps with low friction to use like this in Stellar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now I believe [SEP-7](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md) is the best answer. It defines a link format that an app such as yours can use to create a transaction that you'd like a user's wallet to sign and submit. The flow is this:

- User decides to buy something on your site
- Your site generates a SEP-7 link with the appropriate payment transaction and shows it to the user
- User clicks the link, which opens their wallet
- User confirms in wallet that they want to sign & submit
- wallet signs & submits transaction
- wallet optionally calls back to your app, notifying that the transaction was submitted

Unfortunately, I don't know of any popular wallets that implement SEP-7. See [this question](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/which-wallets-are-supporting-sep-0007).

https://id.stellar.expert/ is a demo wallet that implements SEP-7, so you can use it for testing while wallets are working on adding SEP-7 support, which should be coming soon.